# How to get a certificate type from its file?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have a `X509Certificate` and I want to programmatically determine its type (Extended Validation (EV SSL), Organization Validated (OV SSL) or Domain Validated (DV SSL)).

I read my certificate using BouncyCastle cryptoAPI. For example, this is how I read it from file and get issuer and subject common name (CN):

```
...
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(certfile);                                  
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(input);
X500Name x500name = new JcaX509CertificateHolder(cert).getSubject();
X500Name issuer = new JcaX509CertificateHolder(cert).getIssuer();
...
```

How could I get the type of a given certificate in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using **BouncyCastle 1.57**. If you're using a version < 1.47, the code might be different because in 1.47 they made [significant changes in the API](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Porting+from+earlier+BC+releases+to+1.47+and+later) (although the idea is the same).

To check if the certificate is DV or OV, you can check the [Certificate Policies extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.4), as explained in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35077) and in [GlobalSign's website](https://www.globalsign.com/en-ph/ssl-information-center/telling-dv-and-ov-certificates-apart/):

> ```
> Type                     Policy Identifier
> ```

```
Domain Validated         2.23.140.1.2.1
Organization Validated   2.23.140.1.2.2
```

> Having these identifiers takes us a long way towards our goal of deterministic evaluation of certificate issuance policy — that said, **not all CAs have yet adopted them**.

**Note that this method is not 100% guaranteed, because it's not fully adopted by all Certificate Authorities.** That being said, you can check this extension with BouncyCastle using this:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.x509.extension.X509ExtensionUtil;

X509Certificate cert = // get certificate

byte[] value = cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.32");
if (value != null) { // extension is present
    // CertificatePolicies is a sequence
    DLSequence seq = (DLSequence) X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < seq.size(); i++) {
        // each element is also a sequence
        DLSequence s = (DLSequence) seq.getObjectAt(i);
        // first element is an OID
        String oid = ((ASN1ObjectIdentifier) s.getObjectAt(0)).getId();
        if ("2.23.140.1.2.1".equals(oid)) {
            // DV
        } else if ("2.23.140.1.2.2".equals(oid)) {
            // OV
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The certificate types aren't different in a technical view. It's more an organisational agreement.

You can examine the certificates subject (the variable you called `x500name`). If this field contains values for the keys `jurisdictionOfIncorporationCountryName` and `businessCategory` then you have a EV certificate. The key `serialNumber` then points to some legally registration key for this business entity (like our german *Handelsregisternummer*) and the key CN is the registered name of this business entity.

As far as I know the distinction between DV and OV is more a marketing feature.

Comment: I've made some researchs and i discovered that the certificate type can be obtained from its `CertificatePolicyID`, but i don't even know how to programmatically access this property of a certificate object.